# update text of TextView inside current page of ViewPager from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager and Fragment to display data from sqlite. Content for all page is same so I used same Fragment class for all pages. In fragment there is a TextView. And there are two Buttons in Activity.

I am trying to update text of TextView when any Button is clicked from Activity. For this I used `interface` and override methods in fragment.All works fine.

Note: Buttons are in Activity(common for all pages)

**Problem** 
When I press button it will update textview of next page.  E.g. when I click button in page1 the textview of page2 will be updated and so on.

I used following code. Any help would be appreciate. Thanks.

**Fragment** code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Create a new TextView and set its text to the fragment's section
    // number argument value.
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentview, container, false);
    txtAmount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtAmount);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onPlusClick(String amount) {
    // update textview here

}

@Override
public void onMinusClick(String amount) {
    // update textview here

}
```

**Adapter** code

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummyFragment();

        onClick = (onButtonClick) fragment;

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return arrModel.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return arrModel.get(position).fname;
    }
```

**Activity** code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == btnMinus) {

        onClick.onMinusClick(edtAmount.getText().toString());
    } else if (v == btnPlus) {

        onClick.onPlusClick(edtAmount.getText().toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time getItem is called you are creating a new fragment a assigning it to onClick so onClick is having reference to the latest fragment which in 2nd in your case.

Try creating a list of fragments in constructor of the adapter:

```
List<Fragment> fragments=new List<Fragment>(); 
Fragment currentFragment;
public Myadapter(){
       fragments.add(new DummyFragment());
       fragments.add(new DummyFragment());
} 
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   return fragments.get(position);
}

public Fragment getCurrentFragment(){

    return currentFragment;
}

@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position,
                Object object) {
       super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
       currentFragment=fragments.get(position);
}
```

Then in Activity-

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == btnMinus) {

        adapter.getCurrentFragment().onMinusClick(edtAmount.getText().toString());
    } else if (v == btnPlus) {

        adapter.getCurrentFragment().onPlusClick(edtAmount.getText().toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: then where should I write this line `onClick = (onButtonClick) fragment;` ?

Comment: this button plus and minus are in activity and whichever fragment is visible you want to change the text for that???

Comment: if that is the case then you need a reference to the current fragment and call the onMinusClick function on it.